# Need suggestion for unit testing in Vapor using Swift 3.0

Tags: unit-testing, swift3, vapor

**Do we have any unit testing frameworks in Vapor?**

I am looking dependencies/framework which will help to do the Unit testing some of my web services and methods in easyway.

I've tried following solutions.

- http://seatoncode.com/unit-testing-vapor/
- https://medium.com/@tullio.sebastiani/unit-testing-vapor-toolbox-v-1-0-1-projects-c59a056c3b9b#.qf0kl1pfo

Comment: Vapor 2.0 is going to have some testing conveniences included https://github.com/vapor/vapor/pull/858

Answer (score 1):

Regarding testing frameworks, I'm quite happy with Apple's [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest), but if you're looking for something different, I recommend [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick).

If you also want to test the front-end, there are several solutions out there, and choosing one, in my opinion, depends on what front-end framework you pick, if any.

Anyway, I see you found articles on how to configure Vapor for testing. In [this post](https://theswiftwebdeveloper.com/configuring-vapor-apps-for-testing-7b89f1a6e6a#.tg8kq112p) I do something similar, but also **I made a template to create new apps already set for testing**. You can find it [here](https://github.com/gtranchedone/vapor-testing-template).